# How to reach/consume external endpoints in my cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

First of all I am pretty new on Kubernetes and containerized world.

My scenario is as follows:

I have a application which is deployed to AKS, we are using AGIC as ingress. The application is consuming endpoints hosted outside the AKS. The consumed application is publicly accessible but it has IP whitelisting. I am whitelisting the Application Gateway IP. Also I created a External Service as such.

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-endpoint
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: endpointname.something.com
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 433
```

But it does not work.

Additionally I tried to ping the direct endpoint URL(https://endpointname.something.com) from the pod, and I receive 403.

Can someone advice what would be the correct steps in order to achieve this connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that we fixed this issue by whitelisting the public IP of the AKS load balancer to the target system.